# Fibonacci Rabbits that don't die

Tags: c++

A pair of newly born rabbits (one male, one female) is put in a field. Rabbits are able to mate at the age of one month so that at the end of the second month each pair produces two new pairs of rabbits and then dies.

Note: In month 0, there are 0 pairs of rabbits. In month 1, there is 1 pair of rabbits.

1. Write a program – using a while loop – that takes the number of months from the user and prints the number of pairs of rabbits at the end of that month.
2. In the same cpp file, write a recursive function rabbits() that takes the number of months as input and returns the number of pairs of rabbits at the end of that month.
3. In the main program, call the function rabbits() with the number that the user entered. Output both calculations (i.e. the one you obtained with the loop and the one that the recursive function returns) and see if they are equal.

---

The description is fairly self explanatory. I already have the main program down (regular Fibonacci function), but I can't figure out how to implement the rabbits dying after reproducing. I already know that every other month, the number of rabbits doubles, but I don't know how to implement it. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rabbits (int);

int main ()
{
int x, month, result, counter = 0, rab_now, rab_lastmonth = 1, rab_twomonthsago = 0;

cout << "Please enter the month \n\n";
cin >> month;
cout << "\n";

result = rabbits (month);

while (counter <= month - 1)
{
      rab_now = rab_lastmonth + rab_twomonthsago;

      x = rab_lastmonth;
      rab_lastmonth = rab_now;
      rab_twomonthsago = x;

      counter++;
}

cout << "At the end of month " << month << ", there will be " << rab_lastmonth << "      
pairs of rabbits" << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int rabbits (int month)

{
if (month == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
else if (month == 1)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return (rabbits (month + 1) + rabbits (month - 2));
}
}
```

Comment: The description sounds like regular exponentiation, not fibonacci. At 1 month old, the rabbits mate (but do not give birth). At 2 months old, the pair of rabbits give birth to 2 new pairs, and die. Which is equivalent to giving birth to 1 pair and living forever. Which means every 2 months the rabbit population doubles.

Comment: Originally, if the rabbits lived forever, it would be exactly like Fibonacci, but my professor added the part that they die.

Comment: That makes it exponentiation. Which actually makes it simpler, since all you have to do is double the population every 2 months, without caring about any previous monthly populations.

Comment: you're correct in deducing that "every other month, the number of rabbits doubles", even though the problem is clearly *meant* to have the fibonacci function as its solution (the good fibonacci of pisa was considering just such a rabbit breeding problem). one way to approach a decent simulation is to keep an array of number of rabbits of the possible ages 0, 1 and 2 months. update that array for each mnth passed. with the given problem description at the start of every other mnth the rabbits just age 1 year, and at the start of every other mnth they have offspring and die. is not fib behavior

Answer (score 4):

Your function is almost correct, there’s just one trivial mistake – probably a typo:

```
return (rabbits (month + 1) + rabbits (month - 2));
```

– you want the rabbits from the *previous* month, not the next month. Change the `+` to a `-`:

```
return (rabbits (month - 1) + rabbits (month - 2));
```

And there ya go.

Incidentally, try calling that function with a larger month number – such as 20 or 30. Do you notice anything regarding the performance? Especially compared to the iterative implementation? Can you think of a way to implement the recursive function more efficiently (brain teaser: this isn’t trivial unless you already know how to approach this).

Comment: It was a typo, sorry about that. I didn't notice anything regarding the performance, I think it's because my computer is pretty quick. However, I do understand what you mean by making it more efficient, I'll try to figure it out. I'm new to recursive functions, still trying to fully grasp it. I was wondering, I changed the
    return (rabbits (month - 1) + rabbits (month - 2));
 to 
    return (rabbits (month - 2) + rabbits (month - 2));
That should implement the death right? I tested it out, and it seems to be working.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "this isn’t trivial unless you already know how to approach this" - do you mean tail recursion?

Comment: @Avis Nah, it doesn’t matter how quick the computer is. Try bigger numbers, you’ll see how it slows down very suddenly and very significantly. About the updated recursion, yes, that should model the dead rabbits.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well since you have *two* recursive calls here it’s not enough to introduce one tail call (although it helps with the stack growth). But I was referring to memoisation.

Comment: For some reason, when I enter a month above 5, it gives me a result of 0. Hmm.. what's a tail call? I haven't learned that yet

Comment: You misunderstood what I said. Imagine this Rabbit problem, but instead of the rabbit's dying, they live forever. If that is the case, then it would be the same as the Fibonacci function.

Comment: @avis: it would be a good idea for you to quote *literally* (copy/paste, not retype, and certainly not re-phrase) the problem description. as it now stands it's exponentiation, not fibonacci. if you let the rabbits live forever it would be more than exponential.

Comment: I understand that as it stands now it's exponentiation. I don't disagree with any of you about that. Can somebody explain why if I make it "return (rabbits (month - 2) + rabbits (month - 2));", why does it give me a result of 0 when I enter any number greater than 5?